# How to map or combine multiple array into one array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('student');
$this->db->order_by('studentID','DESC');
$sql1 = $this->db->get();
$result1 = $sql1->result_array();
foreach($result1 as $arr1)
{
    $array1[] = array(
                        'link' => 'student',
                        'values' => '<b>'.$arr1['create_username'].'</b> added new student <b>'.$arr1['name'].'</b>',
                        'dates' => $arr1['s_date']
                    );
}

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('professor');
$this->db->order_by('professorID','DESC');
$sql2 = $this->db->get();
$result2 = $sql2->result_array();
foreach($result2 as $arr2)
{
    $array2[] = array(
                        'link' => 'professor',
                        'values' => '<b>'.$arr2['create_username'].'</b> added new professor <b>'.$arr2['name'].'</b>',
                        'dates' => $arr2['s_date']
                    );
}

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('classes');
$this->db->order_by('classesID','DESC');
$sql3 = $this->db->get();
$result3 = $sql3->result_array();
foreach($result3 as $arr3)
{
    $array3[] = array(
                        'link' => 'classes',
                        'values' => '<b>'.$arr3['create_username'].'</b> added new course <b>'.$arr3['name'].'</b>',
                        'dates' => $arr3['s_date']
                    );
}

foreach(array_combine($array1,$array2,$array3) as $rowss)
{
    echo '<li>
            <a href="'.base_url().''.$rowss['link'].'">
                <p>'.$rowss['values'].'</p>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">'.time_elapsed_string($rowss['dates']).'</p>
        </li>';
}
```

In this code I am simply run three query simultaneously for table `student, professor and classes`. Now, I want to combine or map all array i.e. `array1, array2, array3` which is inside the foreach loop into one single `array`. So, How can I resolve this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: The method you are looking for is array_merge
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: `array_merge($array1,$array2,....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not codeigniter specific. In php you can merge multiple arrays using [array_merge()](http://array_merge) native function

$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

Answer (score 0):

Merging two or more arrays using `array_merge()`

***Syntax:***
`array array_merge($array1, $array2, ......, $arrayn)`

***Here is your code:***

```
<?php

    $array1 = array(
      array(
        'link' => 'student',
        'values' => '1',
        'dates' =>  '01'
      ),
      array(
        'link' => 'student',
        'values' => '2',
        'dates' =>  '02'
      )
    );
    $array2 = array(
      array(
        'link' => 'professor',
        'values' => '1',
        'dates' =>  '01'
      ),
      array(
        'link' => 'professor',
        'values' => '2',
        'dates' =>  '02'
      )
    );
    $array3 = array(
      array(
        'link' => 'classes',
        'values' => '1',
        'dates' =>  '01'
      ),
      array(
        'link' => 'classes',
        'values' => '2',
        'dates' =>  '02'
      )
    );
    $res = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3); 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res);

?>
```

***Output:***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => student
            [values] => 1
            [dates] => 01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link] => student
            [values] => 2
            [dates] => 02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [link] => professor
            [values] => 1
            [dates] => 01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [link] => professor
            [values] => 2
            [dates] => 02
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [link] => classes
            [values] => 1
            [dates] => 01
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [link] => classes
            [values] => 2
            [dates] => 02
        )

)
```